# VB.Net Early Binding class to variable conditionally

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, inheritance

I have an VB.Net application which assigns one of two classes to a variable based on a condition. Currently I'm doing this with pretty straight forward late binding. I'm looking for any other solutions which might improve performance.

Simplified example, I have classes CAT and DOG which both inherit from class ANIMAL. My code looks like this:

```
Dim Pet as Object
Dim Allergic as Boolean = True

If Allergic then 
    Pet = New DOG
Else
    Pet = New CAT
End If

If Allergic then 
   Pet.Bark
   Pet.Fetch
Else
   Pet.Meow
   Pet.UseLitterBox
End Else
```

Anyway to do this so I can early bind to the assigned ANIMAL child class?

Comment: Dynamic dispatch is not the same thing as late binding.  Declare Pet as Animal.  Use polymorphism with the Overridable or MustOverride keywords.  Any introductory book on VB.NET programming will teach you how to do this.

Comment: I understand the concepts you're referring to. I guess I need to include more detail. The derived classes both have many methods and properties not in common with the base class or each other. Do I need to create overrideable/mustoverride methods in the base class for all of them - i.e., do I need to add overridable "Meow" and "Bark" methods to the ANIMAL class if I want to call either from the Pet object? Or is there a simpler method?

Comment: Using your example, if you have a dog and it inherits from an animal, to make it "Bark", you have to CTYPE() your animal to a dog to access the "Bark" method, and your animal to a cat to access the "Meow" method. Otherwise you need to use late binding. The point is, when you have the animal, you can use the methods that are similar like walk, sit, etc.. To access the specific methods, you need the specific Cat/Dog.

Comment: Right, but can I do it with using the same variable ("Pet" in the example), setting it to the DOG or CAT class conditionally, without late-binding. If I declare Pet as Animal, the above code would give an  error that Bark is not a method of the Animal class.

Comment: Also, can I do it without having to declare "Bark" an empty, overridable method in the Animal class. The real-world example I'm working from the "Cat\Dog" are very complex derived classes with many methods and properties unique to them.

Comment: You may be better off giving us a specific, more real (though still short) example, potentially in a new question if it's different enough. Usually these situations are dealt with with polymorphism (as per my answer) and/or generics.

Comment: Declare all common methods in the base class, ANIMAL.  I would recommend that instead of methods named Bark and Meow, you have a method in the base class called Speak and then each Animal overrides the Speak method.

Comment: Again, I guess my example is too simple, and probably needs to be more "real world" as Ben suggests. The issue is really that DOG has .Fetch and CAT has .UseLitterBox - that is, they have many methods not in common, not even on a more abstract level that could be applied to the ANIMAL class. I've gone ahead and created shared methods in the base class where appropriate, declared my variable as the base class (i.e, Pet as ANIMAL) and will just be careful not to reference the non-shared methods from Pet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this. VB.NET requires types to be known at compile time.

Usually, you should attempt to deal with this through polymorphism. You shouldn't put both `Meow` and `Bark` on the `Animal` class (which would violate what's called the Liskov Substitutiton Principle, since `Meow` wouldn't be appropriate for a `Dog` and vice-versa).

Instead, you'd want a method called something like `Animal.MakeNoise`, which a `Dog` would override by barking, and a `Cat` would override by meowing. In this way, `MakeNoise` *abstracts* away the detail of the specific noise to make.